# Android online mediaplayer with seekbar and play pause button

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a list in recyclerview which each item has a play pause button and a seekbar. I finally used this code to make it, but when I click on play button, it crashes and it is not working.

This code works when your media is offline, but when I want to use it on online mode and get the file from a URL, it cause problem.

and the error of android studio indicate to

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(int)' on a null object reference at com.example.wp.VersionAdapter4.startmediaplayer(VersionAdapter4.java:252) at com.example.wp.VersionAdapter4.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$com-example-wp-VersionAdapter4(VersionAdapter4.java:61) at com.example.wp.VersionAdapter4$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)

and it cant get the file as string

How can I fix this?

```
public class VersionAdapter4 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VersionAdapter4.VersionViewHolder>{

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

Context context;

VersionAdapter4 adapter;

private final ArrayList<Version4> versionlist;
private int currentPlayingPosition;
private final SeekbarUpdater seekbarUpdater;
private VersionViewHolder playingHolder;

public VersionAdapter4(Context context, ArrayList<Version4> versionlist) {
    this.versionlist = versionlist;
    this.currentPlayingPosition = -1;
    seekbarUpdater = new SeekbarUpdater();
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public VersionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new VersionViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw3, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VersionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Version4 version4 = versionlist.get(position);
  
    boolean isExpandable = versionlist.get(position).isExpandable();
    holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (position == currentPlayingPosition) {
        playingHolder = holder;
        updateplayingview();
    } else {
        updatenoneplayingview(holder);
    }

}

public void onViewRecycled(VersionViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    if (currentPlayingPosition == holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
        updatenoneplayingview(playingHolder);
        playingHolder = null;
    }
}

private void updatenoneplayingview(VersionViewHolder holder) {
    holder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekbarUpdater);
    holder.sbProgress.setEnabled(false);
    holder.sbProgress.setProgress(0);
    holder.btnplay.setText("play");
}

private void updateplayingview() {
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setEnabled(true);
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(seekbarUpdater, 100);
        playingHolder.btnplay.setText("pause");
    } else {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekbarUpdater);
        playingHolder.btnplay.setText("play");
    }
}

private class SeekbarUpdater implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (null != playingHolder && null != mediaPlayer) {
            playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return versionlist.size();
}

public class VersionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    //  Version3 version = versionsList.get(i);
    SeekBar sbProgress;
    Button btnplay;
 RelativeLayout expandableLayout;
        public VersionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
     
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        btnplay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_play);
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(this);
        sbProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        sbProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Version4 version4 = versionlist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                version4.setExpandable(!version4.isExpandable());
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });
    }
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (getAdapterPosition() == currentPlayingPosition) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } else {
            currentPlayingPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (null != playingHolder) {
                    updatenoneplayingview(playingHolder);
                }
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            playingHolder = this;
            try {
                startmediaplayer(versionlist.get(currentPlayingPosition).getSong());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        updateplayingview();

    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
 private void startmediaplayer(String  getsong) throws IOException {
   
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getsong);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();


    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            releasemediaplayer();
        }
    });



}
    private void releasemediaplayer(){
    if (null!=playingHolder){
        updatenoneplayingview(playingHolder);
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer=null;
    currentPlayingPosition=-1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing a `preparelistener`and `prepareAsync`.

`mMediaPlayer.setDataSource();`

`mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener();`

`mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();`

Comment: I tired it too but didn't work this time it didn't crash but it didn't work too and it gives URL.openconnection() on a null object reference

Comment: then check why null pointer exception occurs. Most it happens is, that an object is null which is attempted to be accessed